# How to extract a string with a regexp?

Tags: php, regex

Can I extract the string `aaa` without using subpatterns (but still using regexp)?

```
$str = 'abc#aaa#abc';
preg_match('/#(.*)#/', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

**Update**

- lookahead and lookbehind is a second solution, any other ?

I'm just trying to figure out some regexp alternatives !

Comment: Just to be clear: you want to capt^H^H^H^H get the text between pound sign using a regex rather than substring and indexOf calls, but not use a subpattern?

Comment: Qtax has a good answer; I will _try_ to think of others. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/(?<=#).*?(?=#)/`

But why wouldn't you want to use a capturing group?

Comment: usually you just need to find a substring and then remove the boundaries

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to look-ahead / look-behind assertions:

```
echo preg_replace('/^.*?#|#.*?$/s', '', 'abc#aaa#abc');
```